# Does tensorflow has similar op like torch.scatter_add so we can do batch aware unsorted_segment_sum?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I'd like to use a batch aware version of tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum but this op only has 1D version.
In order to do unsorted_segment_sum for batch data(data shape like [batch_size, 200, 32], segment_ids shape like [batch_size, 200]) I need to do something like below

```
def unsorted_segment_sum(data, segment_ids, num_segments):  
  num_rows = tf.shape(segment_ids)[0]  
  rows_idx = tf.range(num_rows)  
  rows_idx = tf.cast(rows_idx, segment_ids.dtype)  
  segment_ids_per_row = segment_ids + num_segments * tf.expand_dims(rows_idx, axis=1)  
  num_segments_ = tf.cast(num_segments * num_rows, segment_ids.dtype)  
  seg_sums = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(data, segment_ids_per_row, num_segments_)  
  result = tf.reshape(seg_sums, [-1, num_segments, get_shape(data, -1)])  
  return result
```

But doing this is slow for it's complexity is proportional to batch size.
For torch we can use scatter_add which is much faster for large batch size.

```
def unsorted_segment_sum(data, segment_ids, num_segments):  
  segment_ids = torch.repeat_interleave(segment_ids.unsqueeze(-1), repeats=data.shape[-1], dim=-1)   
  shape = [data.shape[0], num_segments] + list(data.shape[2:])  
  tensor = torch.zeros(*shape).scatter_add(1, segment_ids, data)  
  return tensor
```

So can we using similar op like torch.scatter_add in tf ?